# android emulator camera not working on macbook air

Tags: android, android-emulator

It is my first question on stack overflow, forgive me if i have missed guide.

I have installed android studio 1.0.1 on my macbook air and run the avd.

I have added front and backend camera as emulated.

when i click default camera app of emulator, it shows me blurry screen , no picture view.

First i have tried to search out as much as i can do. no topic found about error related to me.  thats why i have posted my question here. hope senior don't mind.

The screenshots show my avd setting for camera and avd camera app interface:

- http://isb.nu.edu.pk/nusoap/maria/images/esetting.png
- http://isb.nu.edu.pk/nusoap/maria/images/camera.png

I have followed these links, but my problem not resolved.

[Android Camera facing front not working in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522686/android-camera-facing-front-not-working-in-emulator)

[Camera on Android Eclipse emulator:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284583/camera-on-android-eclipse-emulator)

[unfortunately camera has stopped android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975560/unfortunately-camera-has-stopped-android-emulator)

[Camera not working in android emulator 4.2.2, windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751782/camera-not-working-in-android-emulator-4-2-2-windows-8)

[Why the dafault camera not working in android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188532/why-the-dafault-camera-not-working-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

It works as it should, if you want to see picture use webcam instead of emulated. (Emulated shows black-grey grid)

Comment: when i choose webcam as front/back camera, then default camera of emulator crash without showing any thing.

Comment: @Martin why -2 , as this problem really exist, check this link for reference https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95299 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855198/android-emulator-cannot-connect-to-webcam-with-unrecognized-pixel-format-error